# FFmpeg audio crossfade

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, cross-fade

I'm trying to merge several videos using ffmpeg and apply the cross-fade transition in between. I got video cross-fade working by referring to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/778762/crossfade-between-2-videos-using-ffmpeg). At the same time I need to have audio also to have cross-fade applied for original audios associated with each video. I referred several places but they resulted,

> Buffer queue overflow, dropping.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289389/how-do-i-crossfade-between-scenes-in-ffmpeg-using-a-complex-filter), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/880807/crossfading-video-and-audio-with-ffmpeg) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489628/ffmpeg-streams-mixed-when-using-filter-complex-amerge) are few i referred. I got the solution of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/762886/ffmpeg-add-multiple-audio-files-to-video-at-specific-points) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/762886/ffmpeg-add-multiple-audio-files-to-video-at-specific-points) producing the output with `concat` option where the length of the audio is greater than the video. Though I used the exact `fade` values used in video it seams not working like in video.
Following is the ffmpeg command I'm testing.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black -filter_complex "
[0:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=15:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS[va0];
[1:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=30:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS[va1];
[2:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=43:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS[va2];
[3:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=54:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS[va3];
[4:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS[va4];
[5:v]scale=1280x720,trim=duration=69[over0];
[0:a]afade=t=out:st=15:d=2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];
[1:a]afade=t=in:st=0:d=2,afade=t=out:st=30:d=2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];
[2:a]afade=t=in:st=0:d=2,afade=t=out:st=43:d=2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];
[3:a]afade=t=in:st=0:d=2,afade=t=out:st=54:d=2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3];
[4:a]afade=t=in:st=0:d=2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a4];
[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4]concat=n=5:v=0:a=1[outa];
[over0][va0]overlay[over1];
[over1][va1]overlay[over2];
[over2][va2]overlay[over3];
[over3][va3]overlay[over4];
[over4][va4]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" 
-vcodec libx264 -preset fast -r 60 -b:v 45000k -aspect 1.78 -map [outv] -map [outa] -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -shortest test.mp4
```

Also when i use the same `asetpts` as video it result the same issue mentioned above.
What am I doing wrong here and is there any other method that I can use to have both video and audio cross-faded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved the issue by appending silent space to the beginning of each audio following first one. This will mix the audio one after the other.

```
[0:a]afade=t=out:st=15:d=2[a0];
[1:a]afade=t=in:st=0:d=2[a1];
aevalsrc=0:d=15[s1];
[s1][a1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac1];
[a0][ac1]amix[a]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to simplify the command you are using above a bit (for clarity) by reducing to only two video / audio streams, but I think it should apply to 5 videos or more too.

I don't think;

> Buffer queue overflow, dropping.

is an error ... it is warning related to your video. I also get these, but my output seems fine. Maybe someone with more experience can give you more information here.

I think you are having an issue with your audio not working as expected because you are using the `concat` filter. This appends the audio stream to the end of the previous stream. I think what you actually want is to merge / overlay your audio streams like you do with the video streams. This can be achieved with the `amerge` filter:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black -filter_complex "\          
[0:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=5:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS[va0];\
[1:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS+5/TB[va1];\
[2:v]scale=1280x720,trim=duration=10[over0];\                                   
[0:a]afade=t=out:st=5:d=2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];\                            
[1:a]afade=t=in:st=5:d=2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];\                             
[a0][a1]amerge[outa];\                                                          
[over0][va0]overlay[over1];\                                                    
[over1][va1]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" \                                      
-vcodec libx264 -preset fast -r 60 -b:v 45000k -aspect 1.78 -t 12 -map [outv] -map [outa] -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -shortest test.mp4
```

This example takes two videos and fades between them in both audio and video at 5 seconds.